# What does fixed regressor say about our linearity condition?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, stochastic-processes

The linearity condition states that $\mathbb{E}[y_i]=(\vec{x}_i)^{T}\vec{\beta}$ for all $i$. Now, if we have fixed regressors, $\{\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,\cdots\}$, our linearity condition only says for those $\vec{x}_i$, there is a linear relationship. So it does not assume linearity when we have some $\vec{x}_j$ that is not in the set of fixed regressors.

However, if the regressors are random as well, the linearity condition says for all $\vec{x}$ there are, linearity holds. Therefore, if we have an experimental design and had fixed regressors, we can only infer $\vec{x}$ that has happened in the fixed regressor during the experiment and cannot infer otherwise. However, with stochastic regressors, we can infer any $\vec{x}$. Is that right?

Comment: Without an error term in the specification, this is a mathematical question, not a statistical one.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Sorry. I forgot to attach the expected sign. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

No, I would say that the meaning/interpretation of linearity have nothing to do with the question of fixed or random regressors. You say

> So it does not assume linearity when we have some $\vec{x}_j$ that is not in the set of fixed regressors.

But no, the linearity assumption is that the expectation is a *linear function* (well, really an affine function), and as a function the definition must hold for observed as well as non-observed values of the regressor.